# Object leaked: How can i solve this?

Tags: objective-c

when i copy a NSMutableDictionary object into NSMutableArray object like:

```
[array addObject:[dictionary copy]];
```

then i got a memory leak:Method returns an objective-C object with a +1 retain count.

Answer (score 4):

Both `addObject:` and `copy` increase the retain count.

Try `[array addObject:[[dictionary copy] autorelease]]`

Answer (score 1):

If you want to avoid autorelease, You can also try this:

```
NSMutableDictionary temp = [dictionary copy];
[array addObject:temp];
[temp release];
```